# Java Map Deserialization with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I have a simple POJO like

```
public class Employee
{
    int level;
    int salary;

    Map<String, String> details; // HashMap
}
```

A serialized object of this class looks like

```
{"level":1,"salary":30000, "details":{"address":"ADDRESS", "phone":"12345678"}}
```

Assuming the above JSON string is stored in a Java String variable called `json`, 
when deserializing it via the following Jackson statement

```
Employee employee = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, Employee.class);
```

the object is properly created, no exception occurs, the fields "level" and "salary" are correctly populated, but the "details" field (originally a HashMap) is always null.

How can I correctly deserialize it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jackson correctly deserialized the details attribute with the version of Jackson that I have in my machine-1.8.1. Can you confirm that you have accessors created for Employee class, if not that could be the reason.

Comment: You are right, that resolves it, if use a getter method with the correct type (irrespective of its name). Even more cool is that you can tell Jackson to deserialize it as the exact Map type you want via the @JsonDeserialize annotation, e.g. by putting  @JsonDeserialize(as=HashMap.class) before the corresponding field declaration. Thanks!

Comment: Even the getter method is not necessary, if one uses the @JsonDeserialize annotation.

Comment: Hmm, I tried using the JsonDeserialize as @PNS said, but I still get the JsonMappingException "Could not find a (Map) Key deserializer for type..." hmm